# JS: difference between undefined and `undefined`

Tags: javascript, undefined, typeof

Looking at this code; why doesn't a satisfy `(a === typeof a)`

```
var a;
(a === undefined)?console.log("a is undefined"):null;
(typeof a === 'undefined')?console.log("typeof a is 'undefined'"):null;
```

Answer (score 2):

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof `typeof` always returns a string.

Answer (score 1):

Because:

```
var a;
typeof a === 'undefined';
a === undefined;
```

One is a string with the string value `'undefined'`, one is the `undefined` primitive.  Those two are not the same.

`typeof x` always returns string values such as `"undefined"`, `"boolean"`, `"string"`, `"object"`, etc....